# RIAK for Windows 7

Tags: installation, riak

I'm in a process of prepare POC (Proof of Concept) on RIAK.
I've gone through company's website (http://basho.com/riak/) to check whether it's possible to setup RIAK cluster on Windows 7 or not and found that it does not support windows 7 yet.
Just wondering is it possible to setup on windows via cygwin or any other windows base Unix software?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
PS.

Answer (score 5):

Riak is not supported or tested on any version of Windows.

I would recommend using VirtualBox and Vagrant to run a local cluster of VMs on your Windows workstation. The [vagrant-riak-cluster](https://github.com/hectcastro/vagrant-riak-cluster) project will help with that.

Comment: vagrant-riak-cluster does not exists anymore?